# Putting quotes around dynamically generated text in Velocity Templates in Java

Tags: java, velocity, quotes

I am trying to enclose a dynamically generated text in quotes in a Velocity Template. The dynamically generated text can be empty also, so the quotes need not be shown. But if the text is not empty, it needs to be enclosed in quotes.

Can this be achieved using Velocity templates that when the text is empty, the quotes around it disappear?

My code is as follows:

```
#if ($messageFromSender == "") <i></i> 
#else <i>&quot;$!{messageFromSender}&quot;</i>
```

This is the Exception that I get:

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "<EOF>"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the code you provided work at all? Does it give an error?

Comment: after removing the if else added at this point, the template works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can do it. try this -

Lets assume that you have a list `itemList`, which is having text in quotes.

```
List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

itemList.add("\"item1\"");      //item1 in quotes

itemList.add("\"\"");          //no text, just quotes

itemList.add("\"item2\"");     //item2 in quotes
```

Now, add this itemList to the velocity context, add StringUtils object also to the context.

```
context.put("itemList", itemList);

context.put("stringUtils", new org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils());
```

Now, In the velocity template, you can display the texts as-

```
#foreach($item in $itemList)
    #if($stringUtils.length($item) > 2)
        $item //print item if text is not empty
    #else
        //print nothing if text is empty.
    #end
#end
```

`length()` method of `StringUtils` class is used to check the size of the item.

If the text is not empty, the size will be greater than 2. (size of quotes + size of text).

If the text is empty its size will be exactly 2 (size of quotes).

## Output

"item1" //print item if text is not empty.

//print nothing if text is empty.

"item2" //print item if text is not empty.

> Hope it helped ! Let me know for any clarification.

Comment: Thanks Bro. It really helped. I was not adding the end at the last of the if else.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an if statement to check the text value and respond accordingly.

```
#if ($foo == "")
<h1>" "</h1>
#elseif ($foo != "")
<h1>"$foo"</h1>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I faced a problem parsing the template after putting if else. This is what I have put:

Comment: #if ($messageFromSender == "")
              <i></i>
              #else
              <i>&quot;$!{messageFromSender}&quot;</i>

Comment: Please update the question rather than commenting. That way other users can help you more easily